# react-native-navigation-v2 disabledOpenGesture and fixedWidth of sideMenu

Tags: react-native-navigation-v2

I am using the module "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2334".

I want to use block sidMenu opened by swiping and use fixedWidth
I was able to "disabledOpenGesture" option at V1 but I don't know how to apply this option to V2.

I tried like this but it didn't work.

### Code

```
Navigation.setRoot({
            root: {
                sideMenu: {
                    left: {
                        component: {
                            name: Screens.JHDrawerMenu.name,
                            id: Screens.JHDrawerMenu.name,
                            passProps: {
                                items: tabs,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    center: {
                        ...
                    }
                },
                options:{
                    fixedWidth: 150,
                    disabledOpenGesture : false
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable side menu gesture using these options:

```
options: {
  sideMenu: {
    left: {
      enabled: true
    },
    right: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```

This example disables right side menu and enables left side menu gestures.

Fixed width supported in iOS from `react-native-navigation@2.0.2378`

```
options: {
  sideMenu: {
    left: {
      width: 100
    }
  }
}
```